# Error: LogonUser failed with error code 1909

Tags: authentication, winapi

I'm facing with a very strange issue with function LogonUser of Win32 API
(Document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera)

A program contain this function, and when it was called. Sometime it success, sometime it false.

When false, it through this log:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to
> at ImpersonationHelper

The thing I dont understand is every 4 hours, this function will false 1 time, while usename, password and domain value do not change. I dont know why it sometime can execute and sometime can not execute

Anyone have idea for this issue?

Comment: What is hard to understand about "The referenced account is currently locked out"?  That is happening on the domain side, nothing to do with your code. Why it is happening, who knows, ask the domain admin.

Comment: For example, I work for a company whose network locks out my account several times a day for no apparent reason. I login to the company VPN just fine, and start doing work, and a few minutes later I'm locked out, then I wait a few minutes and login back in, and everything is fine for awhile and then I get locked out again. it is really annoying and counter-productive to my work at times when I need to access remote resources on the network.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for comment. Do you think domain admin can check why account lockout? I need confirm because to escalte domain admin, I need open ticket and it'll take fee for me